# SharePoint 2010 Adding extension to the user interface, such as a button on a toolbar or a link on a site settings page

Tags: site-settings

How to add an extension to the user interface, such as a button on a toolbar or a link on a site settings page in SharePoint 2010. I am trying add Site Actions like using Visual Studio 2010 solution by adding Empty element to the solution.

```
<CustomAction
Id="FBAUserManagement"
GroupId="UsersAndPermissions"
Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
Sequence="111"
RequireSiteAdministrator="TRUE"
Title="FBA User Management"
Description="Manage the Forms Based Authentication users in this site collection.">
<UrlAction Url="~sitecollection/_layouts/DWTC/FBA/ShowData.aspx" />
```

After depolyment of the solution, link is not appearing under the "Users and Premissions" in Site Settings page.

Comment: Did you activate the feature containing the element? (Since this appears to be targeted to the site collection, ensure the feature is scoped to "Site").

Comment: yes, Feature is activated, but feature is depolyed to the scopde of "Web", let me try to depoly on Site level.

Comment: No luck even solution is depolyed as and feature is scoped to "Site"

Answer (score 1):

Googled **sharepoint custom action site settings**

Add link to menu:

http://sharepointontop.blogspot.com/2013/03/create-custom-action-in-site.html

Add link to page:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/add-link-to-site-settings-page-in-sharepoint-2010.html#ixzz2anmlCgRw

Let me know if this doesn't help you and I can post a sample.

Comment: Following line is causing the issue on adding the link on Site Setting page "RequireSiteAdministrator="TRUE""

Answer (score 0):

The following line(RequireSiteAdministrator="TRUE") is causing to add the linke on Site Settings Page, I have removed the line and depoly the solution, link start appearing on the page.

```
<CustomAction Id="FBAUserManagement" GroupId="UsersAndPermissions" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings" Sequence="111" Title="FBA User Management" Description="Manage the Forms Based Authentication users in this site collection."> <UrlAction Url="~sitecollection/_layouts/DWTC/FBA/ShowData.aspx" /> </CustomAction>
```